# Segmentation fault while trying to insert node into a linked list

Tags: c, list, insert, segmentation-fault

I started learning C programming a few days ago through the book, Programming in C, and I have prior knowledge of java. Inserting a node into a linked list is very easy in java, but I thought if I could do the same in C.
So, I came up with this program,

```
#include "node.h"

void insertEntry(struct node* root, struct node* after)
{
    struct node* first = root;
    while(first != (struct node*) 0)
    {
        if(first->value == after->value)
        {
            struct node ins;
            ins.value = 3456;
            ins.next = first->next;
            first->next = &ins;
        }
        first = first->next;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    struct node n1, n2, n3;
    struct node* list_pointer = &n1;

    n1.value = 100;
    n1.next = &n2;

    n2.value = 200;
    n2.next = &n3;

    n3.value = 300;
    n3.next = (struct node*) 0;

    void insertEntry(struct node* root, struct node* after);

    while (list_pointer != (struct node*) 0)
    {
        printf("%i\n", list_pointer->value);
        list_pointer = list_pointer->next;
    }
    printf("\n");

    list_pointer = &n1;

    insertEntry(list_pointer, &n2);

    while (list_pointer != (struct node*) 0)
    {
        printf("%i\n", list_pointer->value);
        list_pointer = list_pointer->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

node.h

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node* next;
};
```

Basically, this program takes pointer to the first element of the linked list and the pointer to the element after which it is to be inserted, and inserts a new node after this node.

But when I run this, my program crashes and I cannot find where or why this error occurs.
I looked over to the code in java and tried to implement the same in C.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you used a debugger like `gdb` to find exactly where the segmentation fault occurs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
    {
        struct node ins;  // You create an object in the stack
        ins.value = 3456;
        ins.next = first->next;
        first->next = &ins;   // You reference your object
    }  // Your object is popped out of the stack and ceases to exist
    // Any access to first->next past this block may cause segfault
```

In order to avoid this, you could create `ins` with `malloc()`, but beware: this isn't java and you have to keep track of all objects you allocated in the heap yourself.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is you insert a node that is allocated on the stack -- it's invalid as soon as the function is left. To allocate new memory, you need `malloc()` (don't forget to `free()` when done, there is no garbage collection).

A few side notes:

- It's utterly pointless to cast 0 when used as a pointer to any specific pointer type ... 0 is 0.
- You don't need the root node for inserting, so why pass it in the first place?
- declaring a prototype inside of a function (in that case: main) doesn't make too much sense ... it will work without because the function you want to call is already defined in the same file.
- `#include` headers where they are needed! node.h doesn't need stdio, the main program does.

A version of roughly your program that would work:

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *insertEntry(struct node* after, int val)
{
    assert(after); /* not NULL */

    struct node *new = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new->value = val;
    new->next = after->next;
    after->next = new;
    return new;
}

void freeNodeList(struct node* root)
{
    struct node *current, *last;

    current = root;

    while (current)
    {
        last = current;
        current = current->next;
        free(last);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    struct node *n1, *n2, *n3;
    struct node *ptr;

    n1 = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    n2 = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    n3 = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    n1->value = 100;
    n1->next = n2;

    n2->value = 200;
    n2->next = n3;

    n3->value = 300;
    n3->next = 0;

    insertEntry(n2, 250);

    ptr = n1;
    while (ptr)
    {
        printf("%d\n", ptr->value);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    freeNodeList(n1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, `ins` will become invalid as soon as you leave the `if` block. Once the variable is out of scope, the compiler is free to reuse the memory, even while still executing the same function.

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on gdb and how to use it.

```
gcc -Wall -O0 -g x.c -o x
```

x being your program to compile with debuging information and no optimisation.

then run your program through gdb to find the location/occurrence of the fault.
ie.

```
gdb x
```

Comment: This could be a comment not an answer

Comment: @LPs I'm not allowed to comment yet. Not enough reputation.

Comment: At least not on OP's post.